# Is it possible to get the length of a string including literals

Tags: c++, arrays, function

For example `"hello\0world"` would return a length 12 because there are 12 characters in the string.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sizeof`:

```
char h[] = "hello\0world";

std::cout << sizeof(h);
```

Comment: You would want to divide the total size however by the size of a char, to get the length `sizeof(h) / sizeof(char)` if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: @cairnavron you're right, I was thinking in terms of int's for some reason.

Comment: Well, if you include the division by element size, then you have a generic array length macro.

Comment: @user2364556: "Is it possible to get the length of a string including literals" - `sizeof` as illustrated works for character arrays / literals (you can `sizeof "hello\0world"` without `h[]`, '(' amd ')' around the argument are only needed for types though VC++ used to have a bug and require them) but not when given a pointer to text, so you need to think about when to use `strlen()` and when to use `sizeof()`, and keep in mind that `sizeof()` includes the trailing NUL/'\0' and `strlen()` doesn't.  (Another diff: not all compilers compute `strlen` of literals at compile time.)

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation for char type depends on operating system (16 bit, 32 bit operating system etc). In some operating system there is allocated 2 bytes for char type data. So run the following code & it will give the same result in all operating system:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
 {
            char h[] = "hello\0world";
            cout<<sizeof(h)/sizeof(char);
            return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)==1` *by definition* in the C standard.  `CHAR_BIT` is technically not required to be 8, but the systems where it isn't are few and dwindling.

Comment: Also, there is no `iostream.h` anymore, and operator precedence is not your friend when iostreams are involved.  This particular code happens to do what you expect, but if you had any of the logical or relational operators in there it wouldn't.

Comment: @Zack: +1, but you forgot to mention that `(` and `)` around `h` was unnecessary - and `return 0` too - and `cout` will need to become `std::cout`, and `cout` won't work if you put three '<'s instead of two! ;-o

Comment: @TonyD One has to draw the line between legitimate criticism and nitpicking somewhere.